# scalar function that totals a price result with discount

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm having some troubles figuring out how I can put a scalar function together that has 3 products for 1 order and only 2 products have a discount of .15 applied to them. As you can see I'm pretty new to this, but trying to understand. Thanks for your help.

Code:

```
select distinct(sum (od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity - od.Discount)), o.OrderID
from Orders o
join OrderDetails od
on o.OrderID = od.OrderID
where o.OrderID = 10250
group by o.OrderID
```

This is probably way off regarding how a scalar function should be put together, but I get a total, but it's not applying the discount to the item individually. 
Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If discount is a fixed currency amount, like $5.00, you should use:

```
sum((od.unitprice-od.discount) * od.quantity)
```

If it is expressed as a proportion like .15, you should use:

```
sum(od.unitprice * (1-od.discount) * od.quantity)
```

Note that what you are using here is called an *aggregate function*, not a scalar function.

Also, you should remove `distinct` from your query.  Distinct de-duplicates entire rows.  You can't apply it to a single column in your result, so the parentheses in your query `distinct( sum(...) )` are meaningless.  In this case, there will be no duplicate rows, since you are grouping by orderID, so the distinct has no effect.

You should only use `distinct` when you have a specific reason to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out and let me know in case you have any queries.

# if the discount mentioned after applying the quantity factor

```
select o.order_id,sum(od.unit_price*od.quantity-od.discount) as value  
from
order o
left join
orderdetails od
on o.order_id = od.order_id
group by o.order_id;
```

# if the discount mentioned is for a single item

```
    select o.order_id,sum((od.unit_price-od.discount)*od.quantity) as value  
    from
    order o
    left join
    orderdetails od
    on o.order_id = od.order_id
    group by o.order_id;
```

Hope this helps :)